# SUMO Traci:How to simualte change lane when encountered obstacles

Tags: python, sumo

I want to implement car change lane when encountered obstacles(e.g. illegal parking )
I'm sumo newbie. I know it can be traci achieve but there are few examples of track

I can think of using changeLane of traci but don’t know how to detect obstacles ahead (I use road parking instead)

Please give me some advice,thank u!

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You ’re right, but I still do n’t know how to detect obstacles after searching at http://sumo.sourceforge.net/pydoc/traci.html, I don’t want code                                      I just hope someone can give me a suggestion.  sorry